# Cannot echo the value

Tags: php, count, echo

I just tried to retrieve a value from my mysql databade and tried to print that using php function. But this is not working :( Please help.

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$con=mysql_query("SELECT times FROM counts WHERE item='applemenu';");
$info = mysql_fetch_array($con);
$count==$info['times'];
?>
```

after some html tags

```
<?php echo $count;?>
```

Is there anything wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$count==$info['times'];
```

change this to

```
$count=$info['times'];
```

Comment: OOpps....!!! I forgot that :( Thanks anyway...!! Oh it was that simple. Shit on me :P

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 include("connection.php");
 $input = 'applemenu';
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT times FROM counts WHERE item=?");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$input);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $count);
 mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
 mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
 mysqli_close($con);

 echo $count;
?>
```

Comment: The answer's using mysqli, the question is using mysql. That's the problem.

Comment: but i think now a days everyone has MySQLI extension

Comment: Yes, but using it is a different question. The question is using the obsolete mysql functions - no mysqli connection is created, no wonder your answer is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$con=mysql_query("SELECT times FROM counts WHERE item='applemenu';");
$info = mysql_fetch_array($con);
$count= $info['times'];// This was the wrong with == operator
?>
```

after some html tags

```
<?php echo '$count';?>
```